# Why py-faster-rcnn has 0 detection in trained model with no pretrained weight?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I tested [py-faster-rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) and found that if I don't use pretrained weight then mAP is 0 in testing.

I hope that I should see some value eventhough not very high.

With pretrained model, mAP was above 99%.

Why so difference and how can I solve the issue?

With pretrained weight

```
AP for vertical = 1.0000
AP for horizontal = 0.9500
AP for plate = 1.0000
Mean AP = 0.9833
~~~~~~~~
Results:
1.000
0.950
1.000
0.983
~~~~~~~~
```

Without pretrained weight,

```
AP for vertical = 0.0001
AP for horizontal = 0.0000
AP for plate = 0.0000
Mean AP = 0.0000
~~~~~~~~
Results:
0.000
0.000
0.000
0.000
~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: I changed the convolution layers with xavier weight initialization. I saw some improvements. But not significant.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with all weight initializations and xavier is the best.
We need to initialize weights if not the network doesn't converge.